# Is there a geometric proof stating that: if a=c and b=c. then a=b?

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation

For my problem. It states that there are 2 triangles. **ΔAXB** and **ΔXYZ**. **BX** and **ZY** **⊥ AY**.

**∠1** is **∠AXB**
**∠2** is **∠XYZ**

I know **m∠1 & m∠2 = 90°**
But, I do not know what property I would use as my reasoning for this? Would it be transitive?
Because, **∠1** is '**a**' and **∠2** is '**b**', and **90°** is '**c**', so wouldn't it be: If **a=c** and **b=c**, then **a=b**. But I couldn't find any property that says this, while transitive is: If **a=b** and **b=c** then **a=c**.

If someone could help me answer this question, I will be very grateful!

Comment: For your title, Euclid's first common notion was *"Things that are equal to the same thing are also equal to one another"*

Comment: Just checking, is your problem that the letters are differently? If so, just rename them.

Comment: Using the modern jargon, you're right that transitivity of equality tells you that if $a = b$ and $b = c$ then $a = c$. To deduce your version, you also need to use *symmetry* of equality, which means that if $b = c$, then $c = b$. Then you can apply transitivity. However I think there's almost no situation where you would have to justify this fact - could you elaborate on why you want to justify it so formally?

Comment: Another problem here is what $\angle AXB$ is. If the symbol denotes the measure of the angle, then it is totally ok. However, what if the symbol $\angle AXB$ denotes THE angle, and $\angle AXB = 90^{\circ}$ means "the measure of the angle $\angle AXB$ is $90^{\circ}$"? This is not transitive or symmetric. $\angle AXB = \angle XYZ$ never happens, but $\angle AXB = 90^{\circ}$ happens. However, almost no one is using the symbol in this sense.

Comment: @infinitezero I never thought of that. Thank you for the help! Yeah, I just renamed them and it makes sense now, thanks!